# Parse XML String with Regex.Matches in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

i have a very strange problem which i cannot solve at the moment.

i try to parse a xml string with Regex.Matches to get all xml Nodes with a specific name.

it worked until now.

i have a xml input string with exactly 30 xml nodes named "row"

for some freaky reason my code returns me 26 nodes..
i have actually NO idea why there are 4 missing.

Heres  my code to parse the data:

```
public static List<String> getXMLNodeContentFromSQLQueryString(String queryString, String rowName)
    {
        List<String> returnVal = new List<string>();
        MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(queryString, "<" + rowName + ">.*?</" + rowName + ">");
        foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
        {
            String splitted = match.ToString();
            splitted = splitted.Replace("<" + rowName + ">", "").Replace("</" + rowName + ">", "");
            returnVal.Add(splitted);
        }
        if (returnVal.Count == 0)
            returnVal.Add("");
        return returnVal;
    }
```

heres the xml string

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<EADATA version=\"1.0\" exporter=\"Enterprise Architect\">\r\n\t<Dataset_0><Data><Row><OperationID>5</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>applyForward</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{84137450-8053-46eb-ACD5-574741233ABC}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>6</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>applyBackward</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{416E8BF3-9D6D-4fb3-8C32-05E4E6B8EDDD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>12</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>copy</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EObject</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{E57518A9-9A91-4b0f-9311-F7AF3177F809}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>13</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>embedSDMInEAnnotation</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{44F4A863-86CB-4889-B179-3F4BA1F68D8D}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>18</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>configure</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EBoolean</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>0. Integrator creates GraphTriple and sets roots\r\n1. Adds the given graph triple to the translator\r\n2. Iterates over composite structure of input model and fills unprocessedNodes and unprocessedEdges (other collections are initially empty although this could be different in incremental mode)</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{B22FDBFE-C033-4ff5-81FB-2ED133A55F62}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>19</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>translate</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>TranslationResult</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>136</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{2DFA0837-F09F-40f5-A4BD-CD3857D2D712}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>21</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>determineLNCC</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>Iterate through all rules of the given TGG and consider edges in the following way:\r\nforall edges e in rule r\r\n-&amp;gt; s(e) or t(e) are context elements\r\n-&amp;gt; e is set to create\r\n=&amp;gt; add quadruple containing the types of s(e), t(e), the name of e and the encoded equivalent if s, t or both are context elements.</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{0E021F1A-5CE7-4f68-B737-D2C11AA200ED}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>22</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>determineCandidateRulesForNode</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>CandidateRules</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. Look up in table for operational rules that translate type(node).</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>352</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{7BE07512-219E-40f3-BB81-B1C5B5B15211}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>24</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>isAppropriate</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EOperation</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. check if core match exists in input graph starting from given entry node\r\n2. check if DEC is satisfied (call external method)\r\n3. process context on demand\r\n4. return the corresponding perform* EOperation or null if check failed.</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>183</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{EC74C95A-0D42-4b5d-98C6-0E3273664A8D}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>25</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>updateProcessedSets</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. Determines the corresponding graph elements to the translated objects in the given ruleResult (also edges for translated references!!!)\r\n2. Adds these graph elements to the set of processed elements\r\n3. Be careful not to manipulate the set of unprocessed elements!</Notes><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{CE58DEC9-E683-4d49-8A92-986698AD7ABD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>26</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>buildCandidateRulesLookupTable</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{BC2520AA-DB89-4280-ACE6-F6A8711EDC61}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>28</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>determineCandidateRulesForEdge</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>CandidateRules</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>352</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{1070078F-FF2E-49ca-9432-2D50C026A0D6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>29</OperationID><Object_ID>288</Object_ID><Name>eInvoke</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>java.lang.Object</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{A1D00185-AE82-493e-AAAC-E916D2DD98D3}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>38</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>CREATE</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingOperator</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>115</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{42E99307-46D4-444b-886B-FBA399DF29F6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>39</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>BACKWARD</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>ApplicationTypes</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>5</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>272</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{D0F76449-7205-4f9c-A03D-C68F72A669C4}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>27</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>determineEntryNode</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>TGGObjectVariable</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>128</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{12E442A3-491E-4dc2-9171-728084C3746F}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>30</OperationID><Object_ID>434</Object_ID><Name>invokeOperationWithSingleArg</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EObject</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>288</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{DDE51358-F82B-4100-A5D1-12154D533B41}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>31</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>deriveOperationalRules</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{30584C3D-773E-4256-BBE9-4FD226E45814}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>32</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createOperationalRules</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{ED7EF05C-D74B-4a0f-897D-DB7612AC5AEB}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>35</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>determineOperationSignature</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EString</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{999096A0-B224-4446-A8D5-CB581BA2DD20}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>36</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createPerformOperation</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>Activity</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>5</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>95</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{3414F021-9221-4be2-A133-28E6DAA25ADD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>37</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>convertDirectionToAppropriateDomain</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>DomainType</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>198</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{E83E8FA4-1802-4a2a-AF6B-81D5E4BAB83A}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>40</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>FORWARD</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>ApplicationTypes</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>6</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>272</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{403AA3D8-A275-4763-BB64-8BDF6425EA18}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>42</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createIsAppropriateOperation</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>Activity</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>6</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>95</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{15A6B03B-DDE5-479d-A3DE-FA2A05970DE1}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>43</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>CHECK_ONLY</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingOperator</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>7</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>115</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{16268928-5197-4269-8A3D-5251DD8AA7A6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>44</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>BOUND</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingState</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>8</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>113</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{5529869A-FE95-489e-BB61-BB1F46EBAB87}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>45</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>UNBOUND</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingState</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>9</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>113</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{A3CFAA93-BE84-4602-BAC7-AF42DE44F4AE}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>46</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>SUCCESS</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EdgeGuard</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>10</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>104</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{41D81F5E-E224-4171-A7B5-08BAD5D650E3}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>47</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>FAILURE</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EdgeGuard</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>11</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>104</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{8D2A6AF2-70C9-4d51-ADF2-CBD72BE0D8C1}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>48</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>MANDATORY</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingSemantics</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>12</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>114</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{ADB4946B-AAA6-4ead-97DE-476DE4406DC1}</ea_guid></Row></Data></Dataset_0></EADATA>\r\n"
```

and ideas?

thanks

---

SOLVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Still have no idea where the problem was but solved the problem with using XMLReader thanks for you advices heres the code for interested people.

public static List getXMLNodeContentFromSQLQueryString(String queryString, String rowName)
    {
        List returnVal = new List();

```
    // load contents of file
    TextReader textReader = new StringReader(queryString);

    // process file contents
    XmlDocument domDoc = new XmlDocument();
    domDoc.Load(textReader);

    XmlNodeList nodeList = domDoc.GetElementsByTagName(rowName);
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
        returnVal.Add(node.InnerXml);    
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: **Don't parse XML with regular expressions.** Use an XML API.

Comment: What does parsing the XML with an actual XML parser return? Also, did you try looking /which/ rows are missing? And / or stepping through the code in a debugger to see the code to see why they could be skipped?

Comment: debugging ist not possible because Regex.Matches instantly returns a MatchCollection with 26 entries. No idea why. findind the missing rows is very annoying. i will now try to parse the string with LINQ.

Comment: Change your code so that you create a `Regex` object instance. Then you can use `Match m = re.Match()`, and `m.NextMatch()` until `m.Success != true`. That way you can look at each match individually and determine where it's missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of the non returned rows (the Rows with OperationIDs of 18, 21, 24, and 25), there is one or more "\r\n" in the text, which causes the Regex to not match.  Getting rid of them, or replacing them temporarily will return all 30 rows.

However, using an XML parser as you now have is definitely the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Regex, Add this namespace

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

and then:

```
 var x1 = XDocument.Parse(str);
 var rows = x1.XPathSelectElements("//Row");
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone. Using Linq to XML

```
string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<EADATA version=\"1.0\" exporter=\"Enterprise Architect\">\r\n\t<Dataset_0><Data><Row><OperationID>5</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>applyForward</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{84137450-8053-46eb-ACD5-574741233ABC}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>6</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>applyBackward</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{416E8BF3-9D6D-4fb3-8C32-05E4E6B8EDDD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>12</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>copy</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EObject</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{E57518A9-9A91-4b0f-9311-F7AF3177F809}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>13</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>embedSDMInEAnnotation</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{44F4A863-86CB-4889-B179-3F4BA1F68D8D}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>18</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>configure</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EBoolean</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>0. Integrator creates GraphTriple and sets roots\r\n1. Adds the given graph triple to the translator\r\n2. Iterates over composite structure of input model and fills unprocessedNodes and unprocessedEdges (other collections are initially empty although this could be different in incremental mode)</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{B22FDBFE-C033-4ff5-81FB-2ED133A55F62}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>19</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>translate</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>TranslationResult</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>136</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{2DFA0837-F09F-40f5-A4BD-CD3857D2D712}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>21</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>determineLNCC</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>Iterate through all rules of the given TGG and consider edges in the following way:\r\nforall edges e in rule r\r\n-&amp;gt; s(e) or t(e) are context elements\r\n-&amp;gt; e is set to create\r\n=&amp;gt; add quadruple containing the types of s(e), t(e), the name of e and the encoded equivalent if s, t or both are context elements.</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{0E021F1A-5CE7-4f68-B737-D2C11AA200ED}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>22</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>determineCandidateRulesForNode</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>CandidateRules</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. Look up in table for operational rules that translate type(node).</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>352</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{7BE07512-219E-40f3-BB81-B1C5B5B15211}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>24</OperationID><Object_ID>135</Object_ID><Name>isAppropriate</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EOperation</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. check if core match exists in input graph starting from given entry node\r\n2. check if DEC is satisfied (call external method)\r\n3. process context on demand\r\n4. return the corresponding perform* EOperation or null if check failed.</Notes><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>183</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{EC74C95A-0D42-4b5d-98C6-0E3273664A8D}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>25</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>updateProcessedSets</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Notes>1. Determines the corresponding graph elements to the translated objects in the given ruleResult (also edges for translated references!!!)\r\n2. Adds these graph elements to the set of processed elements\r\n3. Be careful not to manipulate the set of unprocessed elements!</Notes><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{CE58DEC9-E683-4d49-8A92-986698AD7ABD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>26</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>buildCandidateRulesLookupTable</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>1</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{BC2520AA-DB89-4280-ACE6-F6A8711EDC61}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>28</OperationID><Object_ID>273</Object_ID><Name>determineCandidateRulesForEdge</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>CandidateRules</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>352</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{1070078F-FF2E-49ca-9432-2D50C026A0D6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>29</OperationID><Object_ID>288</Object_ID><Name>eInvoke</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>java.lang.Object</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{A1D00185-AE82-493e-AAAC-E916D2DD98D3}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>38</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>CREATE</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingOperator</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>115</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{42E99307-46D4-444b-886B-FBA399DF29F6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>39</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>BACKWARD</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>ApplicationTypes</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>5</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>272</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{D0F76449-7205-4f9c-A03D-C68F72A669C4}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>27</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>determineEntryNode</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>TGGObjectVariable</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>128</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{12E442A3-491E-4dc2-9171-728084C3746F}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>30</OperationID><Object_ID>434</Object_ID><Name>invokeOperationWithSingleArg</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EObject</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>0</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>288</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{DDE51358-F82B-4100-A5D1-12154D533B41}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>31</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>deriveOperationalRules</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{30584C3D-773E-4256-BBE9-4FD226E45814}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>32</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createOperationalRules</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>void</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>4</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{ED7EF05C-D74B-4a0f-897D-DB7612AC5AEB}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>35</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>determineOperationSignature</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EString</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>2</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>0</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{999096A0-B224-4446-A8D5-CB581BA2DD20}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>36</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createPerformOperation</Name><Scope>Private</Scope><Type>Activity</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>5</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>95</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{3414F021-9221-4be2-A133-28E6DAA25ADD}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>37</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>convertDirectionToAppropriateDomain</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>DomainType</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>3</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>198</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{E83E8FA4-1802-4a2a-AF6B-81D5E4BAB83A}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>40</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>FORWARD</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>ApplicationTypes</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>6</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>272</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{403AA3D8-A275-4763-BB64-8BDF6425EA18}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>42</OperationID><Object_ID>165</Object_ID><Name>createIsAppropriateOperation</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>Activity</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>6</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>95</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{15A6B03B-DDE5-479d-A3DE-FA2A05970DE1}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>43</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>CHECK_ONLY</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingOperator</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>7</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>115</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{16268928-5197-4269-8A3D-5251DD8AA7A6}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>44</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>BOUND</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingState</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>8</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>113</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{5529869A-FE95-489e-BB61-BB1F46EBAB87}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>45</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>UNBOUND</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingState</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>9</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>113</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{A3CFAA93-BE84-4602-BAC7-AF42DE44F4AE}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>46</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>SUCCESS</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EdgeGuard</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>10</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>104</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{41D81F5E-E224-4171-A7B5-08BAD5D650E3}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>47</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>FAILURE</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>EdgeGuard</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>11</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>104</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{8D2A6AF2-70C9-4d51-ADF2-CBD72BE0D8C1}</ea_guid></Row><Row><OperationID>48</OperationID><Object_ID>240</Object_ID><Name>MANDATORY</Name><Scope>Public</Scope><Type>BindingSemantics</Type><ReturnArray>0</ReturnArray><IsStatic>0</IsStatic><Concurrency>Sequential</Concurrency><Abstract>0</Abstract><Synchronized>0</Synchronized><Pos>12</Pos><Const>0</Const><Pure>FALSE</Pure><Classifier>114</Classifier><IsRoot>FALSE</IsRoot><IsLeaf>FALSE</IsLeaf><IsQuery>FALSE</IsQuery><ea_guid>{ADB4946B-AAA6-4ead-97DE-476DE4406DC1}</ea_guid></Row></Data></Dataset_0></EADATA>\r\n";
        //s = File.ReadAllText("d:\\test.txt");
        //s = "<string>" + s + "</string>";
        List<String> returnVal = new List<string>();
        string rowName="Row";
        try
        {
            XElement x = XElement.Parse(xmlString);
            var rows=x.Descendants(rowName);
            foreach (var row in rows)
            {
                returnVal.Add(row.ToString().Replace("<" + rowName + ">", string.Empty).Replace("</" + rowName + ">", string.Empty).Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Replace(">  <", string.Empty));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Hope This helps!